# Where is the certificate location to be stored?

Tags: 2013, provider-hosted-app

I created a sample provider hosted app as per microsoft's tutorial using my local box as the remote web server. I am now trying to deploy this project to our staging web server and keep getting the "Access is denied" message after trying to open the App in SharePoint.

I believe this has something to do with the certificate and how I packaged the app. My question is for the paths of the certificates. Does the path need to be local to remote web, sharepoint server, or can I use a server path?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are setting up the app on premise.
Also I am assuming the access denied issue is from deploying to the staging web server and not on your local machine.

In this scenario certificates are stored on the IIS server in the certificate store.

Make sure to [configure both the SharePoint server and the remote web server for S2S](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860570.aspx).

This configuration (using scripts) ensures that the certificate on SharePoint serves a token issuer.

In addition the `TokenHelper.cs` needs to me modified so that it can find the certificate in the certificate store in order to build the access token.